# react-native-bcrypt: Secure PRNG

Tags: react-native, bcrypt

`react-native-bcrypt` ([link](https://github.com/emiraydin/react-native-bcrypt)) throws the following warning.

```
Using Math.random is not cryptographically secure! Use bcrypt.setRandomFallback to set a PRNG.
```

Using `react-native-crypto` ([link](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-crypto)) is a potential solution but feels overly complicated as one has to `nodify` the project. Is there a simpler PRNG that can be set on bcrypt?

Answer (score 7):

You're right... [react-native-bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bcrypt) is the lesser evil among the current libs out there.

To fix the warning, all you need is to supply an alternative random generator library. In the example below, I used [isaac.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isaac).

```js
import bcrypt from "react-native-bcrypt";
import isaac from "isaac";

bcrypt.setRandomFallback((len) => {
 const buf = new Uint8Array(len);

 return buf.map(() => Math.floor(isaac.random() * 256));
});

const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(...)

...
```

Comment: Thank you! I still get the warning about Math.random() not being secure but I see it only once now.

Comment: I believe you should never see that warning at all. Maybe you triggered hashing before setting setRandomFallback(). 

By the way, be careful using Uint8Array.map as it looks like it is incompatible with older versions of react. You can simply use a loop to set generated random values in the buffer.

Comment: That was my understanding but can't seem to figure out why I still get a warning. Just wanted to check in. Thanks for the reminder about map. I already have `Uint8Array.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map` setup to avoid that. Had to figure this out the hard way :)

Comment: I am also getting the warning, and the logs point at the line where you import bcrypt.
Looks like its hard wired to throw that warning once.